# How to estimate moderators of persistence in a panel?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, vector-autoregression

I have a panel dataset of $n$ groups (`i`), observed at a given time (`t`), where we observe a DV (`y`) and some IVs (`x1`, `x2`) at each time point.

Data would look like

```
i   t   y   x1 x2
c_1 1   10  2  10
c_2 2   11  4  11
...
c_n T   15  4  9
```

I am interested in how the IVs moderate the effects of shocks to `y`.

That is: *Are groups who are currently higher in `x` more protected against shocks to `y` such that a shock is less likely to persist in the time series for `y`?*

How would I go about modeling this?